# How do I randomly place value into 10 buttons out of 100 using PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I am currently trying to create a simple game and I just can not come up with the solution. The game is setup just like minesweeper. it has 10 rows and 10 columns so there are 100 blocks(buttons). Right now when you run this using PySimpleGUI the board comes up but when you click a square, either a 1 or 0 shows up on that square.

You can do this for every box on the board and it will give you either a 1 or 0.

I have been trying to get it to randomly select 10 buttons on the grid and divide up 1,000 points randomly among the 10 "Chosen squares" (One square may have 3 points and another could have 700 points).

I am trying to create a simple little "lottery" like game and make it to where the player gets 10 picks to find the most points possible.

I don't know if that makes sense but if so, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any more information.

```
MAX_ROWS = MAX_COL = 10

board = [[randint(0,1) for j in range(MAX_COL)] for i in range(MAX_ROWS)]

layout = [[sg.Button('#', size=(4,2), key=(i,j)) for j in range(MAX_COL)] for i in range(MAX_ROWS)]

window = sg.Window('Mining GUI', layout)

# create the event loop: 

while True: 
    event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
    
        


# window[(row, col)].update('New Text') # to change a button's text, use this pattern
# for this example, change the text of the button to the board's value and turn color black
window[event].update(board[event[0]][event[1]], button_color=('white', 'black')) window.close()
```

Comment: What's exactly your problem? How to make 10 random values to sum up to 1000?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make it to where there are only 10 buttons/boxes on the grid that have values in them (kind of like minesweeper except actually trying to "find the mine"). and then out of those 10 random buttons/boxes I wanted the total to sum up to 1,000 making a score of 1,000 a perfect score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it by `sample` and `shuffle` from `random`.

```py
from random import sample, shuffle
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def generate_data(rows, cols):
    v = sorted(sample(list(range(1, 1000)), 9))+[1000]
    data = [v[0]] + [v[i]-v[i-1] for i in range(1, 10)]+[0]*(rows*cols-10)
    shuffle(data)
    return data

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

MAX_ROWS = MAX_COL = 10
data = generate_data(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COL)
layout = [
    [sg.Button(' ', size=(4,2), key=(i,j)) for j in range(MAX_COL)] for i in range(MAX_ROWS)] + [
    [sg.Text(f"Total {0:>4d}", size=(10, 1), key='SUM')]]
window = sg.Window('Mining GUI', layout)
count = 0
selected = set()
total = 0
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple):
        if event in selected:
            continue
        selected.add(event)
        i, j = event
        v = data[i*MAX_ROWS+j]
        window[event].update(text=str(v), button_color=('white', 'black'))
        count += 1
        total += v
        window['SUM'].update(value=f"Total {total:>4d}")

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This works great. I have another question if you don't mind. If I wanted to make it to where the player only gets 15 chances to find as many of the blocks with points in it how would you do that?

Comment: In my code, there's a variable `count` for how many blocks checked, so you can check if `count >= 15`, then a popup to show 15 chances used, and the score `total`, after `OK` clicked, close the popup and reset all related variables for a new game.

Answer (score 0):

To distribute 1000 points between 10 values randomly you can do the following:

This approach is simple, but not statistically correct (first generated value may be very large, and 9 others will be left with very little score left).

```
bank = 1000
n_chosen = 10
chosen_scores = []
for i in range(bank):
    chosen_scores.append(randint(0, bank))
    bank -= chose_scores[-1]
```

This approach is more fair

```
bank = 1000
n_chosen = 10
bank_indices = list(range(bank+1))
chosen_indices = random.choices(bank_indices, k=n_chosen)
chosen_indices.sort()
chosen_scores = [chosen_indices[0]]
for i in range(1, n_chosen):
    chosen_scores.append(chosen_scores[i] - chose_scores[i - 1])
```

After you have `chosen_scores`, you need to assign which buttons will get the corresponding scores. I'll do the easiest one, but it can be done fancier

```
board_indices = [(i, j) for i in range(MAX_COL) for j in range(MAX_ROWS)]
chosen_button_indices = random.choices(board_indices , k=n_chosen)
for i in range(n_chosen):
    window[chosen_button_indices[i]].update(str(chosen_scores[i]))
```

I can't test if this all works, but that's the idea